# Errors using multiprocesing library on python, the scripts dies

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Im new at python and coding, (I know my code may looks ugly).

I have this little script, that will parse data from some devices.

The inventory function works fine, using a for loop, so only can process one item at the time.

I have added the "main" function, that also works fine if I pass a very short list with a few items in it.
I really do not understand what's going on :/

How can I make the script process more than one item at the time?
any advice pls?

But if add more devices all the script gets broken and the interpreter

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'net_connect' referenced before assignment**

```
lista_dev=["dev1","dev2","dev3","dev4"]

def inventory(router):

        """send commands into network devices and save the collected data as a python dictionary"""
      try:
        net_connect=jump(router,username,password)
    except:
        pass
     facts=(net_connect.send_command("sho ver", use_textfsm=True))[0]
     serial=facts.get('serial')[0]
     config_register=facts.get('config_register') 
     model=facts.get('hardware')[0]
     host=net_connect.send_command("show run | in hostname").split()[1]
     print(host)
     bootflash_content=(net_connect.send_command("dir | in bin", use_textfsm=True))
     current_binaries=[i.get("name") for i in bootflash_content]
     net_connect.send_command("terminal lengh 0")    
     space=(net_connect.send_command("dir", use_textfsm=True))
     free_space=int(space[-1].get("total_free"))
     running_image=facts.get('running_image')
     cpld=(net_connect.send_command("show platform diag | in CPLD").splitlines())[0].split(",")[0].split(" ")[-1]       
      diccionario=({'device': host , 'model': model, 'current_version': running_image,'serial': serial ,
                                'config_reg': config_register,'space_availale_in_bytes': free_space,'clpd_version': cpld,
                                'current_binaries': current_binaries })

 output_q.put(diccionario)

def main():
"""process the list using a Queue to read multiple devices at the time"""
    start_time = datetime.now()
    output_q = Queue(maxsize=5)

    procs = []
    for a_device in lista_dev:
        my_proc = Process(target=device_inventory, args=(a_device, output_q))
        my_proc.start()
        procs.append(my_proc)

    # Make sure all processes have finished
    for a_proc in procs:
        a_proc.join()

    while not output_q.empty():
        #print(output_q.get())
        with open (json_file , "a", encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(output_q.get()+'\n')


main()
```

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "inventory.py", line 38, in device_inventory
    if net_connect is not None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'net_connect' referenced before assignment```
````

Comment: The error is very clear And. I don't see this statament in your code "if net_connect is not None".

Comment: " if net_connect is not None" is part of the code, but is not pasted here.
The error is not clear, to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong with my original code, but using the library concurrent.futures worked smother, than using Queues.

This links help me to figure out.

https://beckernick.github.io/faster-web-scraping-python/#fromHistory